# Postman keeps crashing: "Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed"

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

This is the error I receive in the logs from Postman when it crashes (typically when sending requests):

```
[98038][1681760232816][main][error]["Main~handleUncaughtError - Uncaught errors",{"name":"Error","message":"Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed","stack":"Error: Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed\n    at decirc (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:100:19)\n    at decirc (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:100:9)\n    at decirc (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:100:9)\n    at decirc (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:94:9)\n    at decirc (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:100:9)\n    at stringify (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:25:3)\n    at Format.transform (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/logform/json.js:24:19)\n    at DerivedLogger._transform (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:235:29)\n    at DerivedLogger.Transform._read (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)\n    at DerivedLogger.Transform._write (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:83)\n    at doWrite (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:428:64)\n    at writeOrBuffer (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:417:5)\n    at DerivedLogger.Writable.write (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:334:11)\n    at DerivedLogger.log (/Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:164:14)\n    at /Applications/Postman.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/@postman/app-logger/lib/collectors/AbstractCollector.js:33:23\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)"}]
```

I've Updated to 10.12.13 (most latest) on macOS and cleared Postman cache. Any idea why it keeps crashing?

Comment: This feels like it should be flagged to the Postman team - Can you raise an issue here https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support or contact the support team on help@postman.com please.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and am looking for a fix, as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, clearing the contents of my <user_folder>\AppData\Roaming\Postman\Cache folder resolved the issue for me.

Comment: The MacOS equivalent is `~/Library/Application Support/Postman/Cache`